# When is an instrument too strong in the first stage?

Tags: r, instrumental-variables, 2sls

Instrumental variable regression is estimated with `ivreg` in R. `ivreg` provides diagnostics with the `diagnostics` option in `summary`. The first stage is similar to an OLS regression where the endogenous variable is regressed on all instruments and exogenous variables to check instrument relevance. The *weak instrument test* is often said to be higher than 10 or 20 to indicate good instruments. It is `17.254` in the example below.

My issue is that I often get *weak instrument test* statistics of about 100.000. I am looking for advice on causes and recommendations for "very high" weak instrument statistics.

```
library(ivreg)
data(mtcars)

summary(ivreg(mpg ~ vs + am | disp | cyl, data = mtcars), diagnostics = TRUE)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 29.19516    5.30464   5.504 7.01e-06 ***
disp        -0.04204    0.01506  -2.791  0.00936 ** 
vs           0.43059    2.61832   0.164  0.87056    
am           0.99878    2.18173   0.458  0.65063    

Diagnostic tests:
                 df1 df2 statistic  p-value    
Weak instruments   1  28    17.254 0.000278 ***
Wu-Hausman         1  27     2.346 0.137213    
Sargan             0  NA        NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.312 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-Squared: 0.7272, Adjusted R-squared: 0.698 
Wald test: 26.07 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 2.948e-08
```

I found that the this F-test is calculated as the square of the coefficients t-statistic. Thus my question can be translated into what are potential causes of very high t test statistics in the first stage?

```
summary(lm(disp ~ cyl + vs + am, data=mtcars)) 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   -55.34      97.95  -0.565 0.576616    
cyl            50.85      12.24   4.154 0.000278 ***
vs            -20.55      37.52  -0.548 0.588146    
am            -48.24      26.02  -1.854 0.074294 . 

4.154^2 = 17.25572
```